# Scala method to parse command line arguments without using external libraries

Tags: scala, parsing, arguments, command-line-interface

I have a small module that requires parsing command line arguments with optional parameters.

The function should extract the required parameters, returning them and also returning any additional arguments that were not specified in a separate list.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes. If it's not useful for you, ignore it. If the logic is wrong, post a better version.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this function works pretty well. Also added some scaladoc and a spec to document and test it

Any improvements to make it more "idiomatic"?

Module:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object Utilities {

  /**
   * Parses command line arguments
   *
   * This function parses command line arguments from `args`, as
   * an `Array[String]`.
   * The parameters to be extracted can be prefixed with `-` as default or
   * the param prefix in `paramFormat` (for example `--`) and passed in
   * `parameters` as `List[String]`.
   *
   * The function returns a `Map[String, String]` with extracted parameters and a `List[String]` with remaining arguments that were not extracted.
   *
   * If a parameter does not contain a value and is followed with another parameter (with same prefix), it is ignored.
   *
   * Usage:
   *
   * {{{
   * val args = Array( "-param1", "-wrong", "generated", "singleparam1", "singleparam2", "-anotherparam", "mydata", "-param2", "myboard" )
   * val (params, remaininglargs) = ParseArguments(args, List("param1", "param2"))
   * }}}
   *
   * Results:
   * {{{
   * Map("param2" -> "myboard")
   * Array("-wrong", "generated", "singleparam1", "singleparam2", "-anotherparam", "mydata")
   * }}}
   *
   * @param args the input arguments
   * @param parameters the parameters to be extracted from input `args`.
   * @param paramFormat the param prefix to be extracted (Eg. `-` or `--`).
   * @return a `Map[String,String]` with extracted params and an `Array[String]` with remaining arguments.
   */
  def ParseArguments(
    args: Array[String],
    parameters: List[String],
    paramFormat: String = "-"
  ): (Map[String, String], Array[String]) = {
    var params: Map[String, String] = Map()
    var remainingArgs               = new ListBuffer[String]()
    var lastKey                     = ""
    for (key <- args.toList) {
      key match {
        // Below are the required module parameters
        case p if parameters.contains(p.drop(paramFormat.length)) => lastKey = p.drop(paramFormat.length)
        // Below are the extraction cases. No need to change.
        case param if (lastKey.nonEmpty && param.slice(0, paramFormat.length) != paramFormat) =>
          params += (lastKey -> param); lastKey = ""
        case param if (lastKey.nonEmpty && param.slice(0, paramFormat.length) == paramFormat) =>
          remainingArgs += param; lastKey = ""
        case param if lastKey.isEmpty =>
          remainingArgs += param; lastKey = ""
      }
    }
    (params, remainingArgs.toArray)
  }
}
```

Spec:

```scala
import org.scalatest.flatspec._
import org.scalatest.matchers.should._
import Utilities._

class ParseArgumentsSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers {

  "ParseArguments" should "parse one parameter" in {
    val args                    = Array("-param1", "data1", "generated", "singleparam1")
    val (params, remainingargs) = ParseArguments(args, List("param1", "param2"))

    assert(params === Map("param1" -> "data1"))
    assert(remainingargs === List("generated", "singleparam1"))
  }

  "ParseArguments" should "parse multiple parameters" in {
    val args                    = Array("-param1", "data1", "generated", "-param2", "data2", "-anotherparam")
    val (params, remainingargs) = ParseArguments(args, List("param1", "param2"))

    assert(params === Map("param1" -> "data1", "param2" -> "data2"))
    assert(remainingargs === List("generated", "-anotherparam"))
  }

  "ParseArguments" should "parse one parameter and ignore a wrong one" in {
    val args                    = Array("-param1", "-wrong", "generated", "-anotherparam", "mydata", "-param2", "data2")
    val (params, remainingargs) = ParseArguments(args, List("param1", "param2"))

    assert(params === Map("param2" -> "data2"))
    assert(remainingargs === List("-wrong", "generated", "-anotherparam", "mydata"))
  }

  "ParseArguments" should "parse one parameter with double dash('--')" in {
    val args                    = Array("--param1", "data1", "generated", "--anotherparam", "mydata", "-param2", "data2")
    val (params, remainingargs) = ParseArguments(args, List("param1", "param2"), "--")

    assert(params === Map("param1" -> "data1"))
    assert(remainingargs === List("generated", "--anotherparam", "mydata", "-param2", "data2"))
  }

}
```

Comment: If you want feedback on complete and working code, you might want to  post it over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Nice, never heard about it... posted it because it might be helpful for other people.